# UI state restoring after being closed by the OS

Tags: ios, user-interface, titanium, savestate

I'm writing an iOS application using Titanium. I'd like to ask if there is any module or something like that to achieve what i want. I'm trying to restore the state of my application's UI after the OS stops my app for being in the background for too long or whatever reason. It has a rather complex window hierarchy. For example: the user can open the same window from two different windows. I could store that information in an array like i would do in a stack. But my problem starts when i need to call the creation of each window in order to restore the UI's state. I read that UIKit handles it natively and i'm looking for something that does that or at least simplifies my work.
Thanks!

Comment: "I read that UIKit handles it natively" Yes, it does. Does Titanium mean you can't use that?

Comment: I didn't find anything like that. Maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: Ah. You mean, you know that there's a native state restoration but you don't actually see it? Here's a clue: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_state_restoration